# How do I override generic activerecord error messages in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, overriding

In my en.yml translation file, I have:

```
activerecord:
  errors: 
    template: 
       header: 
         one: "1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved"
         other: "{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved"
```

When an activerecord/validation error occurs during logging into my application, the error message:

> "1 error prohibited this user session from being saved"

is displayed (where user_session is the model being used). I'd rather have it say something like

> "An error has occured to prevent you from logging into your account".

How do I override the generic error message with my specific one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the routes Rails (2.3.8) follows to translate error messages (with i18n 0.6.0):
Also, do not forget to change the full_messages format so that it corresponds with your custom messages.

Here's an example with model "Horse", which validates the attribute "name" (cannot be blank).

In your model(app/models/horse.rb):

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

In your translation file (config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        horse:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Hey, are you the horse with no name?"
      full_messages:
        format: "%{message}"
```

Below is a link to the RoR-guides page where I found this. There's also a list of which messages are required for every variant of validation.

- [ruby on rails guides example and explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)
- [Table with all validations and corresponding messages](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)

The notation and defaults may change with later versions of Rails and/or i18n.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own FormBuilder and change it's translation key.

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling there is an easier way to do it by adding addition entries into the translation file in the models and attributes section, but I haven't found anything that clearly explains how to do it. 
    activerecord:->errors:->models:  AND 
    activerecord:->errors:->attributes: