# How to write active record error message for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'd like to define specific error message for some field of model (e.g. User), which should override the default one (activerecord.errors.messages.invalid) defined in rails-i18n.

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      invalid: "foo"
```

I have tried some structure like

```
activerecord:
  user:
    errors:
      email:
        messages:
          invalid: "bar"
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          email:
            invalid: "bar"
```

It should work fine. See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for further information.

Comment: `Oops, it still doesn't work...` doesn't work as issue description. Please try to be more effective

Answer (score 0):

A similar question looks like it was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493251/how-do-i-override-generic-activerecord-error-messages-in-ruby-on-rails).

You should look into the following sites that were mentioned there should help you:

- [Active record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)
- [Message Interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)